# Como saber o numero do resultado dentro de um loop com mysqli_fetch_array?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Como saber o numero do resultado dentro de um loop com `mysqli_fetch_array` para ter uma condição que separe o primeiro dos restantes?

Na minha tabela `sql` somente contem um único campo inteiro o `id`. O que eu quero fazer é pegar o primeiro elemento que vem da consulta `sql` e tratar o mesmo apenas trocando a cor de escrita do mesmo.

No meu exemplo eu tenho 3 elementos cadastrados no banco de dados eu consigo pegar os 3 mas não consigo isolar somente o primeiro para fazer a alteração de cor

como estou tentando fazer para imprimir os elementos

```
while($aux = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $id = $aux['id'];

    if($id[0]){
        echo "<span style=\"color:red\">$id</span>";
    }else{
        echo "<span>$id</span>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar um contador externo para saber qual é a primeira passagem do loop:

```
$i = 0;
while($aux = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $id = $aux['id'];
    if($i == 0){
        echo "<span style=\"color:red\">$id</span>";
    }else{
        echo "<span>$id</span>";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Outra alternativa é ir criando uma string, e enviar tudo no final:

```
$html = '';
while($aux = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $id = $aux['id'];
    if(strlen($html) == 0){
        $html.="<span style=\"color:red\">$id</span>";
    } else {
        $html.="<span>$id</span>";
    }
}
echo $html;
```